# Images reload after surfing in another tab

Tags: php, html, image

I found a strange bug on my WIP website and I don't know where the problem is. Google couldn't help cause I don't know what to search for.

*Page removed*

and start a new tab and surf along in the web then come back after a while the header and the card disappeared. They seem to reload everytime I come back. The points on top of the card react as normal. They are working fine.

I am using Firefox (Win 7 64bit) latest version. Any suggestion where the problem lies?

Btw. I deleted all my JS to make sure that this is not the problem. The bug still exists.

Edit: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=702579 
Mozilla Firefox is the problem not my code :>

Answer (score 0):

I tried the website you posted with Firefox and Chrome (both latest version on OS X). Described bug did not happen to me.

Since you are using Firefox I suggest you download FireBug extension and then check "Net" tab under "All". If nothing gets loaded it means browser is not sending request to the server again.

Also try updating your browser. It might be some rendering glitch (in case that the content is not getting actually reloaded, that part you'll see after you investigate with FireBug).

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have been designed that way. The header image is supposed to rotate so the site specifies a low expiry time on the HTML and header images. I'm going to assume you've added some kind of plugin designed to create rotating banners and now you're confused that it's doing it.

Have a closer look at the jquery cycle plugin. It may refresh regularly by design.

Comment: makes sense but why does it still appear even if the script is disabled?

Comment: assuming you really disabled your scripts the only logical reason would be you have disabled cache in your browser or you're running plugins/addons that are interfering with rendering.